# inserting multiple changesets in single transaction

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have this bridge table :

```
schema "rooms_units" do
  field(:date_from, :utc_datetime)
  field(:date_to, :utc_datetime)
  belongs_to(:room, App.Room, primary_key: true)
  belongs_to(:unit, App..Unit)
end
```

I have list of maps coming from my endpoint and I made a list of changesets for each map.

```
[

#Ecto.Changeset<
 action: nil,
changes: %{
  date_from: #DateTime<2016-11-03 13:23:00Z>,
  date_to: #DateTime<2016-11-03 13:23:00Z>,
  room_id: 255,
  unit_id: 296
},
errors: [],
data: #App.RoomUnit<>,
valid?: true

#Ecto.Changeset<
action: nil,
changes: %{
  date_from: #DateTime<2016-11-03 13:23:00Z>,
  date_to: #DateTime<2016-11-03 13:23:00Z>,
  room_id: 256,
  unit_id: 296
},
errors: [],
data: #App.RoomUnit<>,
valid?: true
>
]
```

And I want to insert it in the `rooms_units` table in single transaction.

I tried `Ecto.multi.insert_all`. But it accepts list of maps not the changesets.  Is there any other function than can help me with this

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`MyRepo.transaction/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html#c:transaction/2).

```
MyRepo.transaction(fn ->
  Enum.each(changesets, &MyRepo.update!(&1, []))
end)
```

Comment: But it will make inserts separately:
`begin []
 
01:55:34.104 [debug] QUERY OK db=0.7ms
INSERT INTO "table" ...
 
01:55:34.104 [debug] QUERY OK db=0.3ms
INSERT INTO "table" ...
 
01:55:34.106 [debug] QUERY OK db=1.2ms
commit []`

Is there any way to make it in a single insert?

Comment: also is it possible to get back `inserted_at` after such a bulk insert?

Comment: [`Ecto.Repo.insert_all/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Repo.html?#insert_all/3) and [`Ecto.Multi.insert_all/5`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Multi.html?#insert_all/5) do perform a bulk insert, but they do not update calculated fields, like `inserted_at` and `updated_at`, meaning one should prepare and fill them manually.